# Get key and values from Ruby MAP

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to use Ruby MAP in order to get data:

```
PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING = {
    zimpler:              { 'EUR' => ['FI'], 'SEK' => ['SE'] },
    qiwi:                 { 'EUR' => ['RU', 'KZ'], 'RUB' => ['RU'], 'KZT' => ['KZ'], 'USD' => ['UA'] },
    payu:                 { 'CZK' => ['CZ'], 'PLN' => ['PL']},
    entercash:            { 'EUR' => ['AT', 'DE', 'FI'], 'SEK' => ['SE'] },
    carulla:              { 'USD' => ['CO'] }
}
```

I would like to create stub using the above data from the MAP:

```
GirogateRequestBuilder::PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING.keys.each do |payment_method|

        stub_request(:post, /.*/).
         with(:body => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n
          <payment_transaction>\n  
          <transaction_type>#{payment_method.key}</transaction_type>\n  
          <transaction_id>/.*/</transaction_id>\n  
          <usage>New iPad</usage>\n  
          <currency>#{payment_method.get here currency}</currency>\n  
          <billing_address>\n    
             <first_name>Barney</first_name>\n    
             <country>#{payment_method.get here country}</country>\n    
             <state/>\n  
          </billing_address>\n           
              :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Authorization'=>/.*/, 'Cache-Control'=>'no-cache', 'Content-Type'=>'application/xml'})
         .to_return(status: 200, body: successful_response_file)
      end
```

How I can get the proper values from the map?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING.each do |key, value|`:

```
PAYMENT_TYPE_TO_CURRENCY_AND_COUNTRY_MAPPING.each do |key, value|
  # key = :zimpler
  # value = { 'EUR' => ['FI'], 'SEK' => ['SE'] }
```

Comment: For value how I can get the currency? `<country>#{array.keys.first}</country>`?